# How to parse data from link that is using php json_encode

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to parse data from a link, then put them into variables.
I have tried

```
window.onload = function() {
    autoRefreshRadio();
};

function autoRefreshRadio(){
    var disabled = "Unavailable";
    var link = '{"url":"http://itspower.net/fullAPI.php"}';
    var obj = JSON.parse(link);
    alert(obj);
}
```

but it does not seem to alert anything. I'm quite new to Javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why store a string in `link` then parse it? You can do `var obj = {'url': 'http://itspower.net/fullAPI.php'};` instead.

Comment: @Bucket The example is most likely a simplification, and the JSON actually comes from somewhere else that can only hold a string.

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is a JS object. If you want the link string, you need to reference the property it's stored it, `url`:

```
function autoRefreshRadio(){
    var disabled = "Unavailable";
    var link = '{"url":"http://itspower.net/fullAPI.php"}';
    var obj = JSON.parse(link);
    alert(obj.url);
}
```

Although you're doing a lot of unnecessary legwork here. Just store the object in `obj`:

```
function autoRefreshRadio(){
    var disabled = "Unavailable";
    var obj = {"url":"http://itspower.net/fullAPI.php"}
    alert(obj.url);
}
```

Comment: I get [object Object], I would like to put everything into a variable, for example var = obj.dj

Comment: @Aquired No, the above code alerts the URL, not `[object Object]`.

Comment: `var` is a keyword, you cannot store a variable called `var`. Also, what is `obj.dj`? Did you even try this code? It should not alert `[object Object]`. It sounds like you need to read up on elementary JS.